# Where to know the list of NLTK tagset?

Tags: nltk

I need to know what the abbreviations mean, e.g 'VBD', 'NN', etc. I am learning text processing and now I want to get verbs in the sentences, so that I need to know which abbreviations represent any form of verbs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk

Comment: A simple google search can give you the list.

Answer (score 4):

No one answered the question, then I will answer it myself. Thanks to @user12075 for the link. I didn't find it when I was googling it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk

From the above link, I know that nltk uses The Penn Treebank's POS tags.

`nltk.help.upenn_tagset()` will give you the list.